# I want to optimize the following code....(check if a pair of elements in a data-frame exist in another data-frame)

Tags: python, pandas

```
for j in range (0,len(fin1)): 

    for t in range (0,len(data1):

        if fin1.ix[j,0] in (data1.ix[t:t]).values and fin1.ix[j,1] in (data1.ix[t:t]).values:

            fin1['count'][j]+=1
```

-> this is the data-frame named 'fin1' containing two values in a row, I wish to count the number of times the set of all these rows occurs in the another data-frame

```
   0    H1  I1
   1    H1  M1
   2    H1  AD1
   3    H1  AE1
   4    H1  AF1
   5    H1  AQ1
   6    I1  M1
   7    I1  X1
   8    I1  Z1
   9    I1  AA1
  10    I1  AB1
   ...  ... ...
```

-> this is the other data-frame 'data1'

```
   0    B1  C1  D1  E1  F1  G1  H1  I1  J1  K1  ... AZ1 BA1 BB1 BC1 BD1 BE1 BF0 BG1 BH0 BI1

   1    B1  C1  D1  E1  F1  G1  H1  I1  J1  K1  ... AZ1 BA1 BB1 BC1 BD1 BE1 BF1 BG1 BH1 BI1

   2    B1  C1  D0  E1  F1  G1  H1  I1  J1  K0  ... AZ1 BA0 BB1 BC0 BD1 BE1 BF1 BG1 BH0 BI1

   3    B1  C1  D1  E1  F0  G1  H1  I0  J1  K1  ... AZ1 BA0 BB0 BC1 BD1 BE0 BF1 BG1 BH1 BI1
```

The code I have written runs quite slow, I know there is a better way to do this, please help me out....
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please insert codes, rather than pictures in the question statement. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Removed pictures, please help with the code...